# "Studying the variation of these rate functions" or "Studying the variations of these rate functions"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, academic-writing

I am trying to express the following idea: "studying the variation of function f1 and the variation of function f2 w.r.t. the number of active users N is essential for ....". Note that we can use these functions instead of f2 and f1.
Here is my attempt:

> Studying the variation of these rate functions w.r.t. the number of active users N is essential for ...

In this attempt, should I use `variation` or `variations`? `is` or `are` ?

Comment: Variation can be either a process or a result.  So, the answer depends on what you study, the process of making changes to the function, or the multiple results of applying those changes.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I am not sure I understand your point. Could you please elaborate on that a little further ?

Comment: Example: "the function is subject to variation due to..." -- in this case it's a process, and is singular.  Or, "in our experimentation with initial conditions we found at least three variation**s** of the function..." -- here it's the result, and is plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how many differences are there between the two functions.

If there is a single difference use the singular 'variation' and 'is' otherwise use 'variations' and 'are'